# How to throw an Observable error

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have this method in **Angular 4**:

```
modifyStock(id: number, quantity: number) {
  const url = `/item/${id}/modifyStock`;
  const body = { quantity: quantity };

  return this.http.put(url, body);
}
```

I want to control if any of the input parameters are `null` and just don't call the `http.put()` if it happens and then **throw an error that must be catched in the `subscribe()`** method that call this one.

I tried with this and some combinations like `throw Observable.throw('Error')` but I can't get it to work.

```
modifyStock(id: number, quantity: number) {
  if (id == null || quantity == null) {
    return Observable.throw('Error');
  }

  const url = `/item/${id}/modifyStock`;
  const body = { quantity: quantity };

  return this.http.put(url, body);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work **how**?

Comment: @torazaburo Typescript was complaining about it

Comment: Please provide the TS error.

Comment: @torazaburo `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`. I call it with `this.myService.modifyStock(id, 1).subscribe(() => {});` (simplified example that gives error too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have your observer throw an error:

```
this.data = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(42);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(43);
      }, 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
         observer.error('bla');
      }, 2500);

      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.throw` should work. Make sure to import it correctly.

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

You sould be able to use it as you've done in your example.

```
test() {
  this.modifyStock(1, null).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('success');
  }, 
  err => {
    console.log('error', err);
  })
}

modifyStock(id: number, quantity: number): Observable<any> {
  if (id == null || quantity == null) {
    return Observable.throw('Error');
  }

  const url = `/item/${id}/modifyStock`;
  const body = { quantity: quantity };

  return this.http.put(url, body);
}
```

Comment: TS don't stop to give me this error: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` even if I write the subscribe like this: `this.modifyStock(1, null).subscribe(() => {});`

Comment: @J.J.Bocanegra You should explicitly declare the return type as `: Observable<any>` in this case. I've updated my answer.

Comment: throw is deprecated